# C# late bound non exist property

Tags: c#, .net

how check is property exist? like

```
if propertyName in obj
{
}
```

because there is some moments when obj doesn't have such property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach using reflection is:

```
        PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyNameToFind");

        if (info != null)
        {
            // Property exists in this type...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at the [System.Reflection.PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class.

Here is a sample usage

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |                                               BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos, delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

// write property names
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos) {
    Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```